# Why does Citus error with certain boolean constraints?

Tags: postgresql, citus

If I run this query:

```
SELECT "t1"."id" FROM "session" AS t1 WHERE ("t1"."dirty" = TRUE) ORDER BY "t1"."id" LIMIT 1000;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error : ERROR:  unsupported clause type
```

This query works perfectly on a local table. Why is Citus raising an error when I use it on a distributed table?

Answer (score 4):

instead of:

```
"t1"."dirty" = TRUE
```

use:

```
"t1"."dirty" IS TRUE
```

Comment: Yep, this is the workaround! We've merged a fix https://github.com/citusdata/citus/pull/388 which will get released with Citus 5.1

Comment: Citus 5.1 is now out and includes the fix for this, but anyone on 5.0 or earlier can use this workaround (which should be accepted!)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
WHERE t1.dirty
```

I mean, this is a boolean right?